# Living in the US on an F2 visa and working remotely for a Canadian company

Tags: usa, canada, visa

I'm aware I can't work in the US on a F2 visa. However, would it be possible to be employed by a Canadian company to work remotely from the US?

Comment: I'm not sure about F2 visas, but broadly (in most cases), you can't work in the US (for anyone, anywhere) unless you're entitled to work within the US itself. Checking if there's any caveats to that particular visa.

Comment: Would you be taking residency in the US?  An alternative would be to still be technically resident in Canada, but spend as much time in the US as possible without requiring residency there.

Comment: @TimPost +1 For extremely important consideration. Straying to the wrong side is a punishable crime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discussion of the same for the [person working in India](http://forum.murthy.com/index.php?/topic/51128-can-i-get-f2-visa-without-resigning-job-in-india/) the answer is overwhelmingly no.  The reason is that any income from any source has to be reported on the Tax Returns that you will have to file with the IRS (yes even with the Foreign Student status), so the money you're making from your job in Canada will come up (unless of course you're going to commit tax fraud, which is a different discussion).

So having that money will violate your F-2 status.

There may be other options available such as the case similar to:

- [Are H4 visa holders allowed to do remote intellectual work?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/61/are-h4-visa-holders-allowed-to-do-remote-intellectual-work?rq=1)

Which may allow you to own the company in the US but not receive any funds from it but whether or not this is legal, how to set such entity up, and what it would entail to your employment in Canada is a matter for lawyers, accountants, and your current employer.

Additionally, depending on where you live in Canada and your wife's school location it may be possible to get an [F3 Student Visa](http://matamoros.usconsulate.gov/non-immigrant_visas/visa-categories/catf.html) which will allow you to live in Canada but will make your wife commute to school across the border.

Comment: But an F3 visa is for Mexicans and Canadians. "his visa is for Canadian or Mexican citizens who maintain their residence outside the United States and commute to the United States temporarily in order to engage in full- or part-time academic studies." I suppose the Original Poster would need to be Mexican or Canadian to avail of this?

Comment: @drN That is correct.

Comment: "So having that money will violate your F-2 status." What is your basis for claiming that having US taxable income is a violation of F-2 status?

Answer (score -1):

There are many debates about that, and several law firms who says that this is a possibility.

http://immigration.lawyers.com/ask-a-lawyer/can-i-work-for-my-home-country-while-on-f2-dependent-visa-451936.html

http://www.nationofimmigrators.com/employment-based-immigration/immigration-lawyers-arguing-can-i-work-from-home-for-a-foreign-employer/